# Launching SimpleHTTPServer in background

Tags: python, bash, shell, simplehttpserver

I am trying to write a shell script that launches a server and then fires up a browser to view the served content

```
(cd app && python -m SimpleHTTPServer) &
open http://localhost:8000
```

Disclaimer: I'm new to bash scripting and I don't really know python.

It seems that when adding the `&` operator at the end of the line, the process doesn't stay alive long enough to remain functional.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure about the problem with running in the background with `&`, but to get something working quickly might try using [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) invoked with the options `-dm` (to run the command in the background by starting detached).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (probably) not that the server doesn't stay alive long enough; it's that it doesn't start up fast enough. When the `open` command executes, the webserver hasn't started yet, so you get an error.

Try sleeping for a second or two before the `open`